# Getting the xml node depending on the child value using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have one XML like below

```
<BackgroundReports>
    <BackgroundReportPackage>
        <Screenings>
            <Screening type="PEMP">
                <ScreeningStatus>
                    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
                    <ResultStatus>Review</ResultStatus>
                </ScreeningStatus>
            </Screening>
            <Screening type="PEMP">
                <ScreeningStatus>
                    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
                    <ResultStatus>Review</ResultStatus>
                </ScreeningStatus>
            </Screening>
            <Screening type="FEMP">
                <ScreeningStatus>
                    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
                    <ResultStatus>Fail</ResultStatus>
                </ScreeningStatus>
            </Screening>
            <Screening type="PEMP">
                <ScreeningStatus>
                    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
                    <ResultStatus>Pass</ResultStatus>
                </ScreeningStatus>
            </Screening>
            <Screening type="TEST">
                <ScreeningStatus>
                    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
                    <ResultStatus>Review</ResultStatus>
                </ScreeningStatus>
            </Screening>
        </Screenings>
    </BackgroundReportPackage>
</BackgroundReports>
```

I want to get the only one `Screening` element of attribute type `PEMP` and `FEMP` depending on the priority value in `<ResultStatus>` value.

If XML has result status `<ResultStatus>Fail</ResultStatus>` then get only that Screening element has `<ResultStatus>Fail</ResultStatus>`

Ouuput will be

```
<BackgroundReports>
    <BackgroundReportPackage>
        <Screenings>
            <Screening type="FEMP">
                <ScreeningStatus>
                    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
                    <ResultStatus>Fail</ResultStatus>
                </ScreeningStatus>
            </Screening>
            <Screening type="TEST">
                <ScreeningStatus>
                    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
                    <ResultStatus>Fail</ResultStatus>
                </ScreeningStatus>
            </Screening>
        </Screenings>
    </BackgroundReportPackage>
</BackgroundReports>
```

It removed 3 FEMP/PEMP Screening elements from original XML.

Second priority is `Review` (if Fail is not there) - `<ResultStatus>Review</ResultStatus>` but also get only one element if multiple/all Screening elements with `Review`

Third is Pass (if Review and Fail is not there), but also get only one element if multiple/all Screening elements with `Pass`

Also it should list other `Screening` elements other than `PEMP` and `FEMP`

Here is the xslt I worked so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.cpscreen.com/schemas"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
    xmlns:my="http://www.fadv.com" exclude-result-prefixes="my fn xs xdt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <!-- Copy the current node -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Including any attributes it has and any child nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/ns0:BackgroundReports/ns0:BackgroundReportPackage/ns0:Screenings">
        <test><xsl:value-of select="count(ns0:Screening)"/></test>
        <xsl:variable name="eduResultStatus"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Screening[@type='PEMP' or @type='FEMP']">
            <!-- Yet to work here -->
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Screening[@type != 'PEMP' and @type != 'FEMP']">
            <xsl:copy>
                <!-- Including any attributes it has and any child nodes -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you share the XSLT code that you have written so far? It would be helpful if you can also add the desired output based on the priorities mentioned above. Do you want to have all the `Fail` first, `Review` next and `Pass` in the end of the output XML.

Comment: @AniketV Updated

Comment: @AniketV yes, Fail first, Review next and Pass in the end of the output XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using XSLT 2.0, you can declare a sort order and split the values

```
<xsl:param name="sortOrder" select="'Fail,Review,Pass'" />
<xsl:variable name="valSequence" select="tokenize($sortOrder, ',')"/>
```

Perform the sorting on the `ResultStatus` using the declared order for `Screening` element having `@type` values as `FEMP` and `PEMP` and get the 1st element in the output

```
<xsl:for-each select="Screening[@type = 'FEMP' or @type = 'PEMP']">
    <xsl:sort select="index-of($valSequence, ScreeningStatus/ResultStatus)" />
    <!-- Get 1st element after sorting -->
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

For the remaining nodes, apply them as is

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Screening[not(@type = 'FEMP' or @type = 'PEMP')]" />
```

The complete XSLT is as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:param name="sortOrder" select="'Fail,Review,Pass'" />
    <xsl:variable name="valSequence" select="tokenize($sortOrder, ',')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Screenings">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Screening[@type = 'FEMP' or @type = 'PEMP']">
                <xsl:sort select="index-of($valSequence, ScreeningStatus/ResultStatus)" />
                <!-- Get 1st element after sorting -->
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Screening[not(@type = 'FEMP' or @type = 'PEMP')]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<BackgroundReports>
   <BackgroundReportPackage>
      <Screenings>
         <Screening type="FEMP">
            <ScreeningStatus>
               <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
               <ResultStatus>Fail</ResultStatus>
            </ScreeningStatus>
         </Screening>
         <Screening type="TEST">
            <ScreeningStatus>
               <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
               <ResultStatus>Review</ResultStatus>
            </ScreeningStatus>
         </Screening>
      </Screenings>
   </BackgroundReportPackage>
</BackgroundReports>
```

Comment: I need only one Screening  element for PEMP and FEMP

Comment: Do you mean you want one from each `ResultStatus`?

Comment: No I need only one element `<Screening type="FEMP">`after sorting , it can be either FEMP or PEMP depending up on sort. I got the result from your xslt. Just need to pull the first `Screening ` element of your sort result

Comment: In that case it will pull the first Screening of FEMP or PEMP. Sort won't get applied

Comment: I need sort then get first element

Comment: If you don't mind can you please give the code. Im beginner in xslt

Comment: I have updated the answer to pick the first element after sorting. Please check if it helps. The output has also been updated.